# Edit XML tags using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT and am having problems trying to alter my XML sheet that is based on a format that is not desired.

I need to rename all the `<Column>` Elements to the appropriate elements `<test1><test2><test3><test4><test5><test6><test7><test8><test9>`.

See below:

```
<Csv>
  <Row rowNo="1">
    <Column>1999-01-02T10:30:20</Column>
    <Column>200</Column>
    <Column>17</Column>
    <Column>1</Column>
    <Column>15</Column>
    <Column>10</Column>
    <Column>210</Column>
    <Column>main strip Top</Column>
    <Column>Tyre Check</Column>
  </Row>
  <Row rowNo="2">
    <Column>2014-03-08T10:30:20</Column>
    <Column>200</Column>
    <Column>17</Column>
    <Column>1</Column>
    <Column>45</Column>
    <Column>14</Column>
    <Column>520</Column>
    <Column>main strip Left</Column>
    <Column>Tyre Fixed</Column>
  </Row>
</Csv>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the exact output you expect for your current input please? It may also help if you removed the blank lines from your input XML too. Thank you!

Comment: I'm very sure that you don't want `<test1><test2><test3>` element names. Element names with counters are bad and wrong and you should not try to use them anywhere.

Comment: @Tomalak: you are entirely right, but sometimes you need to produce XML for consumption by some other application or library... and I think we all know how "good" some people are at understanding XML's use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not 100% certain this is what you're looking for, the following stylesheet will result in what I believe is the output you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Row/Column">
        <xsl:variable name="count">
            <xsl:number />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:element name="test{$count}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input, it produces...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Csv>


<Row rowNo="1">

<test1>1999-01-02T10:30:20</test1>

<test2>200</test2>

<test3>17</test3>

<test4>1</test4>

<test5>15</test5>

<test6>10</test6>

<test7>210</test7>

<test8>main strip Top</test8>

<test9>Tyre Check</test9>

</Row>


<Row rowNo="2">

<test1>2014-03-08T10:30:20</test1>

<test2>200</test2>

<test3>17</test3>

<test4>1</test4>

<test5>45</test5>

<test6>14</test6>

<test7>520</test7>

<test8>main strip Left</test8>

<test9>Tyre Fixed</test9>

</Row>
</Csv>
```

What the XSLT does is, by default it will copy any element, text node, attribute and other input. If it encounters a `Column` element in any `Row` element, it will first put the result of `<xsl:number />` in a variable. This is in effect the element's rank within the `Row`. Then it creates an element with name `test` followed by that variable value, and applies templates to any attribute or node within the current `Column` — necessary to make sure the text content and any other nodes/attributes are copied.

Comment: @christiankatterloher Don't forget to accept if it's the correct answer to the question ;)